# SSL HttpWebRequest to site with mismatched certificate on Azure?

Tags: c#, ssl, httpwebrequest, azure

We have a client with mismatched SSL certificates in their QA environment.  We’re making HttpWebRequest calls to those SSL-protected web resources from within an Azure web role.  To get around their certificates, we set ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy to a new policy that accepts all certificates.  This works in a full trust environment, but fails with a SecurityPermission exception when we try to set the CertificatePolicy within the less-than-full-trust Azure environment.  Is there a way that we can make those calls work from within our Azure service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question!

Apparently, to run it in full trust you simply need to enableNativeCodeExecution="true" in the web role configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be something?

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate (
    object sender,
    X509Certificate cert,
    X509Chain chain,
    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        return true;   //Is valid
    }
    //Add the mismatched certificate hashstring below. 
    //That way only that resource will be affected and not all certificates will be trusted.
    if (cert.GetCertHashString() == "99E92D8447AEF30483B1D7527812C9B7B3A915A7")
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```